# How to connect to a beckhoff CB3263?

Tags: twincat

We have a beckhoff cb3263 with some IO blocks on loan and I am trying to let it do anything. So far I am not a fan of TwinCat. I found it to be not user-friendly and very complicated. I can only hope that I can eventually write C++ programs for it.

I followed tutorials and created a simple PLC program which I can compile in TwinCat.

But no tutorial seems to explain how to get the program in the actual PLC. Eventually I found how to connect but ofcourse it does not work...

I tried: settings -> choose target -> search (ethernet) -> broadcast search. And there is nothing showing up. I have both laptop and PLC wired to a switch and it has an IP address assigned. However  I cannot ping the beckhoff from my laptop. I do can ping my laptop from the PLC.

I have also another issue with TwinCat. I want to activate the trial license but I get the message "invalid system ID". This ID is defaulted to alot of zeroes in TwinCat and I cannot change this. How can I change the device ID?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bas

EDIT:
I can ping in both directions but I get the messages Destination Host unreachable

Comment: Which TwinCAT version are you using, TwinCAT 3? I can't find that cb3263 from anywhere. In some networks the broadcast search won't work. Try to write the IP manually to the text box in the route dialog (upper left corner) and click "Enter host name / IP". If you find it, do try to check also the "IP address" radio button instead of "Host name". Let's see the license problem after you can make a route to the PLC.

Comment: I have activated the trial license with help of Beckhoff support. There was a very simple but yet vital step missing from the 'getting' started page which was necessary.  cb3263 is the motherbord, that's my mistake, I'm sorry. The Beckhoff PC is a CP6700-0001-0050. I still don't have any clue how to transfer a program in the PC nor how I should interact with the IO. I cannot succesfully scan my wired IO box